# Linux authentication on Microsoft Active Directory using sssd

Tags: linux, authentication

I am currently trying to have a Linux server (Red Hat Enterprise 7.6) to authenticate users based on a Microsoft Active Directory.
The idea would be to allow the users to connect via SSH to upload documents to their personal website without giving them access to a shell.

To cut the story short, we are a school and we want to provide access to a personal dedicated folder to our students.

I am trying to use SSSD which sounds promising. I am able to join the domain and, when I increase the log level I see the users being cached on my linux server. I have meticulously followed the Red Hat documentation and most of the posts discussing the usage of SSSD but I might be missing something somewhere.
I wanted to progress gradually and, before getting SSH involved I wanted to first try to authenticate a user locally on a console (not through SSH). The user is not configured as a local user. It is only defined in the Active Directory.

But it fails with the following message in /var/log/secure:

```
Dec 10 09:42:05 svx-pub-01 login: pam_unix(login:auth): check pass; user unknown
Dec 10 09:42:05 svx-pub-01 login: pam_unix(login:auth): authentication failure; logname=LOGIN uid=0 euid=0 tty=tty1 ruser= rhost=
Dec 10 09:42:07 svx-pub-01 login: FAILED LOGIN 1 FROM tty1 FOR (unknown), User not known to the underlying authentication module
```

As far as I understand, the sssd is not involved in the authentication here and I would like to understand why.

I know that my future goal is to authenticate the users via SSH but I first want to make a very simple local test... So I have defined a default shell in the sssd.conf file. The only value that I have modified for confidentiality purpose id "mydomain.com" which is not the real value :)

```
[sssd]
domains = mydomain.com
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam
debug_level = 7

[domain/mydomain.com]
ad_server = svw-dc-00.mydomain.com
ad_domain = mydomain.com
krb5_realm = mydomain.com
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = ad
debug_level = 7
[pam]
debug_level = 7

[ssh]
```

Here is the /etc/krb5.conf

```
# Configuration snippets may be placed in this directory as well
includedir /etc/krb5.conf.d/

includedir /var/lib/sss/pubconf/krb5.include.d/
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true
 rdns = false
 pkinit_anchors = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
# default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
 default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}

 default_realm = MYDOMAIN.COM
[realms]
 MYDOMAIN.COM = {
 }

[domain_realm]

 mydomain.com = MYDOMAIN.COM
 .mydomain.com = MYDOMAIN.COM
```

Here is the /etc/nsswitch.conf

```
passwd:     files sss
shadow:     files sss
group:      files sss
initgroups: files sss

#hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
hosts:      files dns myhostname

# Example - obey only what nisplus tells us...
#services:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#networks:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#protocols:  nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#rpc:        nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#ethers:     nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#netmasks:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files sss

netgroup:   files sss

publickey:  nisplus

automount:  files sss
aliases:    files nisplus
```

And the /etc/pam.d/system-auth

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok] pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok] pam_localuser.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so forward_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     optional      pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so umask=0077
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     optional      pam_sss.so
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your valuable input.

Comment: Can you query the user information via nsswitch (using `id <name>`, `getent passwd <name>`, `getent -s sss passwd <name>`)? What is the user's UID?

Comment: The command `id <name>` gives `id: <name>: no such user` and the command `getent passwd <name>` retrurns nothing, not even a message.

Comment: When I enter the command `realm join -U <user> ads.mydomain.com` it says `realm: Already joined to this domain`

Comment: But! When type `getent -s sss passwd <user>@mydomain.com` I receive an answer like: `<user>@mydomain.com:*:153324743:153200513:Lastname Firstname:/home/<user>@mydomain.com:/bin/bash`
How is it possible to get rid of the "@" when I proceed to the login because it make the console login impossible

Answer (score -1):

In sssd.conf change `use_fully_qualified_domain_names = True` to `False`

You will have to restart the sssd service and possibly clear out the cache in `/var/lib/sss/db/` for this to take effect

You may also want to change `fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d` to `fallback_homedir = /home/%u` unless you want everyone's home directories to have the @[domain] at the end

Comment: some reasoning behind the theoretical need for this would be helpful